# Connect iOS devices over local WIFI

Tags: ios, networking, wifi

I am researching (with little luck) how to connect two iOS devices over local wifi to exchange data. I only want the router to be in between to phones, no internet.

Could somebody point me in the right direction with this aim?

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Check out [Bonjour for Developers](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/index.html)

Comment: Don't forget about the Multipeer Connectivity framework :)

Comment: Check out this code (it's in andorid though): https://github.com/omerjerk/RemoteDroid